# How to toggle light and dark modes on elements with hard-coded style variables like `--shiki-dark:#D8DEE9` using Next.js and Tailwind

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to use [shikiji](https://github.com/antfu/shikiji) to render markdown code blocks in my Next.js 14 site. shikiji basically just inserts HTML elements where light and dark modes are "hard coded" into the CSS.

```html
<pre
  class="shiki shiki-themes min-light--nord"
  style="background-color: #ffffff;--shiki-dark-bg:#2e3440ff;color: #ffffff;--shiki-dark-bg:#2e3440ff"
  tabindex="0"
>
  <code>
    <span class="line">
      <span style="color:#1976D2;--shiki-dark:#D8DEE9">console</span>
      <span style="color:#6F42C1;--shiki-dark:#ECEFF4">.</span>
      <span style="color:#6F42C1;--shiki-dark:#88C0D0">log</span>
    </span>
  </code>
</pre>
```

[Demo](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antfu/shikiji/main/packages/shikiji/test/out/dual-themes.html)

In order to sync these values with the user's mode (light/dark), shikiji suggests applying a [media query-based css rule](https://github.com/antfu/shikiji#query-based-dark-mode) or a [class-based one](https://github.com/antfu/shikiji#class-based-dark-mode).

I have copied the media query into the `globals.min.css` file of my Next.js app which already is set up with Tailwind.

```css
// globals.min.css

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .shiki,
  .shiki span {
    color: var(--shiki-dark) !important;
    background-color: var(--shiki-dark-bg) !important;
    /* Optional, if you also want font styles */
    font-style: var(--shiki-dark-font-style) !important;
    font-weight: var(--shiki-dark-font-weight) !important;
    text-decoration: var(--shiki-dark-text-decoration) !important;
  }
}
```

*but* when I toggle dark mode, nothing happens. I should note that I am also using [next-themes](https://github.com/pacocoursey/next-themes) with the following theme provider, and this works as expected with regards to my tailwind classes.

```js
// providers.jsx

"use client"

import { ThemeProvider } from "next-themes"

export function Providers({ children }) {
  return <ThemeProvider attribute="class" defaultTheme="dark">{ children }</ThemeProvider>
}
```

[image]